# Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting the following error:

> Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection
>   with new rows

and I have no idea why it's happening. It's happening in else part.

```
Using ta As New dsUsersTableAdapters.wsm_Contact_UserTableAdapter
    ta.FillByContactID(dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User, p_User.ContactID)
    If dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dsContactUserrow = dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User.Rows(0)
        With dsContactUserrow
            .Active = p_User.Active
            .UserType = p_User.UserType
            .UserID = p_User.UserID
            .Answer = p_User.Answer
            .QuestionID = p_User.QuestionID
            .ExtUser = p_User.ExtUser
            .Locked = p_User.Locked
        End With
    Else
        dsContactUserrow = dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User.Newwsm_Contact_UserRow
        With dsContactUserrow
            .ContactID = p_User.ContactID
            .UserID = p_User.UserID
            .Active = p_User.Active
            .UserType = p_User.UserType
            .Password = p_User.Password
            .Answer = p_User.Answer
            .QuestionID = p_User.QuestionID
            .ExtUser = p_User.ExtUser
            .Locked = p_User.Locked
        End With
        dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User.Addwsm_Contact_UserRow(dsContactUserrow)
    End If

    ta.Update(dsContactUser.wsm_Contact_User)
End Using
```

Comment: It appears that your table adapter has it's `UpdateCommand` set but not its `InsertCommand`, which does seem odd.  I've seen it the other way around but not that, so I don't really know what you've done wrong or failed to do. The fact that you have no idea suggests that you don't know how table adapters work, so I'd suggest that you learn before going any further. [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx) and read as much as you can.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to know EXACTLY how you created that table adapter. The only common reason that I'm aware of for an `InsertCommand` not to be generated is that the query used involves a join of multiple tables. SQL code cannot be automatically generated to insert to multiple tables so the `InsertCommand` will be `Nothing`. In that case though, the `UpdateCommand` should be `Nothing` too, which seems not to be the case here.  If something went wrong in the wizard then regenerating the `DataSet` may be the best course of action. TBC...

Comment: ...Regardless of anything else, you can always open your `DataSet` in the designer, select your table adapter, open the Properties window and then examine and/or modify the `InsertCommand` property manually.  You really should already have done that because you should have researched table adapters enough to know to look there.